# Type.GetFields return an empty System.Reflection.FieldInfo array for public fields

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class that contains only a number of public fields of rather standard types.
The call `myObject.GetType().GetFields()` returns an empty array.

What can the problem be?

UPDATE:
I am sorry folks, the problem was that I was using a class exposed by WCF service. The original class (say A) and the exposed (WcfReference.A) are different classes. A's members become private fields in WcfReference.A and exposed as properties.

Perhaps the question should be deleted.

Comment: "rather standard types" is certainly a universal definition, but sample code would be better ;)

Comment: You're sure that your type has fields and not properties?

Comment: Making fields public is a pretty bad idea.  Maybe you did it correct after all.  Post repro code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GetFields() without arguments will return the public Fields (not properties as @Kenneth Ito noticed) of your type.

example

```
public class Test {
   public string var_;//I'm a public field, I'll be returned
   private int id_; //I'm a private field, you'll have to do more to get me
   public int Id {get { return id_;} set {id_=value;}} //I'm a property, I don't feel concerned
}
```

if you do

```
var test = new Test();
test.GetType().GetFields();
```

will return an array with one item : var_

Comment: I think this is a correct answer in the end of the day. In a way it answers the question.

Comment: This is only true post .NET 1.1, and there is an overload for `GetFields()` that I've outlined how to work with it below to get just the private fields.

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of .NET (I'm adding functionality to a 1.1 project, pity me), the default method `GetFields()` will return an empty array. After 1.1, they updated this method to include all public properties. I don't know why they made this change, as there is already a `GetProperties()` method which will do the same thing.

This method is the way to get at private fields, so knowledge of how to work with it is critical. There is an overload for the method [GetFields(BindingFlags flags)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/6ztex2dc(v=vs.110).aspx). This uses a combination of [BindingFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx) to determine which fields you want from your object.

So if you want instance private fields, you would call:

```
GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

If you only want public static properties, you would call:

```
GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
```

You can also continue to combine them for all static fields:

```
GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

There are many other types of `BindingFlags`, so check out the MSDN page linked above for any others you might need.